# How to run laravel projects with lower PHP version?

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

So I have these projects that are set to PHP 7.3 and the other is PHP 7.2. I have a Mac with PHP 8 as the installed version. If I try to run the laravel projects with

```
composer install
```

or even with update. It always tell me that the versions are conflicting. Now I tried to use lower versions of PHP using brew, right? I got past the version concerns while doing the composer install, but the problem is when I go to browser (I use laravel valet by the way). This is the error and the site doesn't show up :

```
Deprecated: Method ReflectionParameter::getClass() is deprecated in /Users/astaire/code/@Laravel_projects/hs-ticketing/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 853
```

What do I need to update or downgrade?

Comment: Have you considered using Docker (Compose)?

Comment: I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: That depends on the versions of PHP and Laravel - can you share more details about them?